# C++ Interfaces in stl::list

Tags: c++

LessonInterface

```
class ILesson
{
    public:
        virtual void PrintLessonName() = 0;
        virtual ~ILesson() {}
};
```

stl container

```
typedef list<ILesson> TLessonList;
```

calling code

```
for (TLessonList::const_iterator i = lessons.begin(); i != lessons.end(); i++)
    {
        i->PrintLessonName();
    }
```

The error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   passing ‘const ILesson’ as ‘this’
>   argument of ‘virtual void
>   ILesson::PrintLessonName()’ discards
>   qualifiers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "put" objects of a class that has pure virtual functions(because you can't instantiate it). Maybe you mean:

```
// store a pointer which points to a child actually.
typedef list<ILesson*> TLessonList;
```

---

OK, as others pointed out, you have to make `PrintLessonName` a `const` member function. I would add that there is another small pitfall here. `PrintLessonName` must be `const` in both the `base` and the `derived` classes, otherwise they will **not** have the same signature:

```
class ILesson
{
public:
    virtual void PrintLessonName() const = 0;
    virtual ~ILesson() {}
};


class SomeLesson : public ILesson
{
public:
    // const is mandatory in the child
    virtual void PrintLessonName() const
    {
        //
    }
    virtual ~SomeLesson() {}
};
```

To be honest, I find [Jerry Coffin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601457/c-interfaces-in-stllist/1601534#1601534) answer helpful for redesigning the printing functionality.

Comment: While this is true, it the error message jack has pasted isn't due to this error.

Comment: tried and Error is :

Description Resource Path Location Type
request for member ‘PrintLessonName’ in ‘* i.std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = ILesson*]()’, which is of non-class type ‘ILesson* const’

Comment: I didn't observe the const issue, my eyes first fell on `typedef list<ILesson> TLessonList;`. Anyway, he has to fix this one also.

Comment: @jack: try `(*i)->PrintLessonName()` instead. Since you are using pointers now, dereferencing the iterator yields a pointer instead of an object instance.

Answer (score 10):

PrintLessonName must be declared as const to be able to be called on const ILessons. Otherwise the compiler assumes it may modify the ILesson and prevents the call.

```
virtual void PrintLessonName() const = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `iterator` instead of `const_iterator` or make `PrintLessonName()` const function:

```
virtual void PrintLessonName() const = 0
```

Comment: Ugh. What about making the function `const` instead? It's not like we'd expect printing to change the printed object.

Comment: Read my answer "OR MAKE THE THE FUNCTION CONST"

Comment: Ah, my brain worked like AraK's here. Read the removing `const` suggestion and pavloved to down-voting. Sorry. I'll remove my down-vote (but won't up-vote as long as you suggest removing `const`).

Comment: @sbi these are the syndromes of overtime on SO ;)

Comment: @sbi and what if I want to increment a counter in PrintLessonName() that will count how many print where done. agree not the best code in the world but possible. Also as a rule of thumb don't put const on virtual methods since you don't know how someone is going to use them.

Comment: @AraK: Actually not. It's more a syndrome of me stealing precious time somewhere else to be here and then not reading thoroughly because I feel like I steal to much. `:)`

Comment: @Shay: That depends. If that counter is something users of that lesson can observe, then going against expectations might be worth considering. If not, then that counter isn't part of the logical constness of the object and it should probably be `mutable`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make PrinLessonName const.

```
virtual void PrintLessonName() const = 0;
```

Or not use a const_iterator, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You want a list of pointers to ILesson's.

IMO, you'd also be considerably better off adding something like:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, ILesson const *il) { 
    il->PrintLessonName(os);
    return os;
}
```

Then, instead of the loop you've written above, you can use something like:

```
std::copy(lessons.begin(), lessons.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<ILesson *>(std::cout));
```

As you can see, I've added one other minor embellishment in the process -- PrintLessonName takes a stream as its argument, instead of always printing to the same place. Of course, if you're not using streams, you may not want that...

Edit: Of course the other comments that you want to make PrintLessonPlan const are also correct...

Answer (score 1):

**You call a non-const method for a const object refered through a reference to const object.**

Anyways:

I'm 100% sure you need to have a list of pointers:

```
typedef list<ILesson*> TLessonList;
```

in order to take advantage of polymorphism.

Having a list of values of ILesson is not possible, since ILesson is an abstract class.

Don't forget to delete the objects in the list of pointers, to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

A version like this:

```
for (TLessonList::const_iterator i=lessons.begin(), m=lessons.end();  i!=m;  ++i)
    {
        i->PrintLessonName();
    }
```

lessons.end() gets called once, and also note ++i instead of i++, which is faster (the post-increment operator involves creation of a temporary object, while the pre-increment doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

People are correct about the lack of const.
I'd favour using the for_each algorithm this will prevent calling lessons.end() for every entry.

```
#include <algorithm> //for for_each()
```

Then use this:

```
std::for_each(  lessons.begin(), lessons.end(), std::mem_fun(&ILesson::PrintLessonName) )
```